# Find index where change in columns occurs for large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```py
data = {'A':  ['p1', 'p2',"p3",'p1', 'p2',"p3",'p1', 'p2',"p4"],
        'time': [0,0,0,40,40,40,80,80,80]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['A','time'])
df.set_index(["time"],inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```
    A
time    
0   p1
0   p2
0   p3
40  p1
40  p2
40  p3
80  p1
80  p2
80  p4
```

I would like to know at what time, and for what entries does column `A` change.

For example, a slow non-vectorised approach would be (you would loop in the time index):

```py
t0 = df.loc[40]["A"].unique()
t1 = df.loc[80]["A"].unique()
print("out: ")
print(set(t0).difference(t1))
print("in: ")
print(set(t1).difference(t0))
```

output something like:

```
at t=80:
out: 
{'p3'}
in: 
{'p4'}
```

Some catches are:

- speed matters
- you can't always rely on the time difference being `40`,
- `p1`,`p2`,`p3` can change order

Any ideas how to do this more pandas-like?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you only doing `40` vs `80`, are you looking for all combinations? Consecutive ones?

Comment: Right, sorry, the time index goes from `0` to lets say `10000` in increments of mostly 40. Maybe 80 sometimes. The point is that not too much emphasis should be put on the actual values of the time index, but rather the `A` column.
And yes for all combinations and consecutive ones, but only from one time window to the next, if that makes sense? I.e., if 2 items in `A` change from 0 to 40, then it needs to catch both of them. But if there's a change from 0 to 80, but not in 0 to 40, then it can skip those.

Comment: ... If there's a change from 0 to 80, but not in 0 to 40, then it can skip that and just report the change in 40 to 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something with this strategy:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['time'])['A'].unique().reset_index()

time    A
0   0   [p1, p2, p3]
1   40  [p1, p2, p3]
2   80  [p1, p2, p4]
```

now shift the previous row:

```
df2['B']=df2['A'].shift(1)

time    A               B
0   0   [p1, p2, p3]    NaN
1   40  [p1, p2, p3]    [p1, p2, p3]
2   80  [p1, p2, p4]    [p1, p2, p3]
```

now create a function such that finds your diff in/out:

```
def foo(a,b): 
    try:        
        rin = set(a.tolist()).difference(set(b.tolist()))
        rout = set(b.tolist()).difference(set(a.tolist()))
        return "in: "+str(rin)+" out: "+str(rout)
    except:
        return ""
```

and apply it:

```
df2['diff'] = df2.apply(lambda x: foo(x['A'],x['B']), axis=1)
```

Desired result:

```
time    A               B               diff

0   0   [p1, p2, p3]    NaN X
1   40  [p1, p2, p3]    [p1, p2, p3]    in: set() out: set()
2   80  [p1, p2, p4]    [p1, p2, p3]    in: {'p4'} out: {'p3'}
```

You can now improve the foo function as you see fit